# google maps API complex markers in Safari iphone

Tags: javascript, html, iphone, google-maps

I have a map built and in a desktop web browser it looks good with my complex icons.  When i load the map on my iphone, i see markers, but they are not complex, they are the default markers. any ideas why?

Both i.title and color vars are set and contain valid values.

```
          success:function(result){
                var color = result;
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                       position: myLatlng,
                       title:i.title,
                       icon:{
                           path:google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
                           scale:8,
                           fillColor:color,
                           fillOpacity:1,
                           strokeColor:"#000000",
                           strokeWeight:4
                        }
                });
                marker.setMap(map);
          }
```

Comment: This calls for basic debugging first. Is this `success` function ever called? (for quick and dirty debugging, do an `alert()` in it)

Comment: yea, everything works perfectly fine in a web browser.  success is called, color is #xyzxyz,  icons get drawn.  only in on my iphone, they are drawn as the default google maps marker, on desktop browser, they are circles with color fill of #xyzxyz

Comment: Is this `success` function ever called *on the iPhone*?

Comment: yes, the markers are drawn, just not with the icon info.

Comment: Ah, I see, the markers are set in the function as well. Hmm, not sure what is going on here